# Enter a three digit number and write a function that adds the numbers together - Homework Warning

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I have this homework problem with functions.  I can get the user's string input into an array of numbers, but I cant figure out how to then add them.  I tried doing a for loop but this seems like Im going down the wrong path.

Question: 
Allow a user to enter a three digit number.
Write a function that adds the numbers together.
Hint #1: You need to turn a string into an integer.
Hint #2: Strings can be treated as arrays too.

Here is my code:

```
    document.getElementById('submitBtn3').addEventListener
    ("click",     function ()) {

    var digits = document.getElementById('digits').value;
    var digitsArray = digits.split(',').map(function(i) {
        return parseInt(i, 10);
    })

    console.log(digitsArray);
    document.getElementById('q11').innerHTML = digitsArray;
    })
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: You can just use Number('123') to turn a string input into a number

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues,

- a closed parenthesis without the following block for the function

  ```
  ("click",     function ()) 
  //                       ^
  ```
- splitting with `split(',')`, which works only for joint arrays, like `1,2,3`, but not with a string, without commas. You need here an empty string `split('')`.

Now you can add the single numbers in another loop, or extend the first loop with an addition.

```js
document.getElementById('submitBtn3').addEventListener("click", function() {
    var digits = document.getElementById('digits').value;
    var digitsArray = digits.split('').map(function(i) {
        return parseInt(i, 10);
    });

    console.log(digitsArray);
    document.getElementById('q11').innerHTML = digitsArray;
});
```

```html
<input id="digits">
<button id="submitBtn3">go!</button>
<div id="q11"></div>
```

Just a hint for completeness.

Strings have a `length` property. This helps to iterate through a string with a loop of choice. The access inside could be with [`String#charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) or with brackets and an index, like `string[index]`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

document.getElementById('submitBtn3').addEventListener("click", function() {
  var digits = document.getElementById('digits').value;
  var sum = digits.split("").map(function(n){return parseInt(n)}).reduce(add,0);
    
  document.getElementById('q11').innerHTML = sum;
});
```

```html
<input id="digits" type="number"/>
<button id="submitBtn3">go!</button>
<div id="q11"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one might be more homework answer friendly than using a 1 line .map

```js
function myFunc() {
  var num = document.getElementById('digits').value;
  var tot = 0;
  num.split('').forEach( function (x) {
    tot = tot + parseInt(x,10);
  });
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = tot; 
}
```

```html
<input id="digits" />
<button onClick="myFunc()">Submit</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```